# What is the faster way to retrieve a column using minimum of another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a faster way to perform the following query?

I need to find `pod.podId` according to min of another column `DueDate` in the same table.

```
DECLARE @sodi = 7 -- this is the function parameter

select top 1 
    pod.podId
from 
    sod 
inner join 
    idt on sod.ItemID = idt .ItemID
inner join 
    pod on pod.ProductID = idt.ProductID and pod.DueDate is not null and (pod.OrderQty >= pod.ReceivedQty)
inner join 
    poh on poh.poID = pod.poId and poh.StatusID <>32
where 
    sod.soid = @sodi
    and pod.DueDate = (select min (pod.DueDate)
                       from sod 
                       inner join idt on sod.ItemID = id.ItemID
                       inner join pod on pod.ProductID = id.ProductID and pod.DueDate is not null and (pod.OrderQty >= pod.ReceivedQty)
                       inner join poh on poh.poID = pod.poId and poh.StatusID <> 32
                       where sod.sodID = @sodi)
```

Comment: Why not just say `select min(duedate) from pod`? Is joining to other table necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select top 1 pod.podId
 from sod 
 join idt 
   on sod.ItemID = idt .ItemID 
  and sod.soid = @sodi
 join pod 
   on pod.ProductID = idt.ProductID 
  and pod.DueDate is not null 
  and (pod.OrderQty >= pod.ReceivedQty)     
 join poh on poh.poID = pod.poId 
  and poh.StatusID <> 32
order by pod.DueDate, pod.podId
```

My moving the condition up into the join something the query optimizer gets smarter

Comment: Same as other answer and sallusahn was first +1

Comment: Be aware you could have more than 1 pod.podId with the same minumum DueDate

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the `Order By` on `pod.DueDate`

```
DECLARE @sodi = 7 -- this is the function parameter

select top 1 
    pod.podId
from 
    sod 
inner join 
    idt on sod.ItemID = idt .ItemID
inner join 
    pod on pod.ProductID = idt.ProductID and pod.DueDate is not null and (pod.OrderQty >= pod.ReceivedQty)
inner join 
    poh on poh.poID = pod.poId and poh.StatusID <>32
where 
    sod.soid = @sodi
order by pod.DueDate
```